# linker command failed while running mbalertview demo

Tags: objective-c, mbprogresshud

I downloaded mbalertview from the git and try to compile and run but i got this error

```
_vImageBoxConvolve_ARGB8888", referenced from:
-[MBFlatAlertView boxblurImage:boxSize:] in MBFlatAlertView.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

please help me.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently `vImageBoxConvolve_ARGB8888()` is not defined. See if the [Accelerate framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Accelerate/Reference/AccelerateFWRef/_index.html) is properly included in the project.